# Why does maxWidth on a Button not work and how to work around it?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I have two buttons on the layout, and on a large-screen device (tablets) I want to cap their width so they don't look ridiculous. I expected to use the maxWidth attribute but it apparently does nothing in my scenario. Here's the layout definition - the buttons use up the full width of the layout, ignoring any value in maxWidth.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
>
<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:maxWidth="100dp"
    android:text="Button 1"
/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:maxWidth="100dp"
    android:text="Button 2"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Why, and how to workaround this (apparently crazy) limitation?

Comment: Why are the buttons layout_width 0dp and not wrap_content?

Comment: @antlersoft - 0dp width in combination with a layout_weight matching that of sibling elements will ensure that they are the same width as each other

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Remove the `android:layout_weight="1"` line from both buttons. 

Add `android:minWidth="50dp"` and `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

EDIT:

You need to calculate the button sizes manually depending on the screen size. First you need to have a standard screen size set. For example, If the you develop the app on a screen width 400px, and the button is 100px wide, then the formula for maintaining the same `button width to screen width` ratio on all devices will be as follows

```
 DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
 getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
 buttonWidth = 100 * (metrics.widthPixels/400);
```

Use case: 
If screen width = 480px, then button width should be 120px.

Comment: Why? The buttons then won't scale at all, and will have a width of zero

Comment: Thats what is causing the buttons to stretch to fill whole width of the layout. Set the minwidth also and change the width to `wrap_content` not 0dp.

Comment: If I remove the layout_weight the button won't scale, which is what I want it to do. I want a button that scales with device sizes but only to a maximum size.

Comment: if you use `dp` for dimensions then drawables will scale automatically for different densities. You cannot do it for different sizes.

Comment: I could do it dynamically, but that's a pretty brute-force approach. I was hoping there was  away to convince the framework to work as I expected it to. I am going to look at subclassing Button to include dynamic resizing, but also look at using various layout variants to avoid the need.

Comment: "You need to calculate the button sizes manually depending on the screen size" -> Please never do this

Answer (score 3):

The **good way** of solving this is to create multiple layout for different combination of screen resolution. When you get at some max stretch, create a new layout that have fixed value where needed. See the section about "Use layout alias" in http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseAliasFilters

Answer (score 1):

Width/Height seem to always ahve to be set together,.. This is working in my view

```
        <Button
            android:text="Center"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/selectionCenterButton"
            android:minWidth="50dp"
            android:minHeight="50dp"
            android:maxWidth="100dp"
            android:maxHeight="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
```

The button's parent is set to wrap content, so scales down, but up to a max of 400 wide (4 buttons)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the layout_width to wrap_content vs. 0dp.

Comment: This is one of many variants I've tried. It doesn't make any different.