# LinearLayout even width distribution, but no wider than x

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have LinearLayout(horizontal) and I would like its children to have equal width, but, no more than some value.

The code below does not work.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxWidth="20dp"
            android:text="Button 1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxWidth="20dp"
            android:text="Button 2" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxWidth="20dp"
            android:text="Button 2" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this?
Thanks.

Comment: Explain more your question is not clear.

Comment: Duplicate: [Why does maxWidth on a Button not work and how to work around it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205282/why-does-maxwidth-on-a-button-not-work-and-how-to-work-around-it)

Comment: I have LinearLayout. During launch time I add dynamicaly fragments to this layout, those fragments are simple FrameViews with background color. I would like them to have equal size, but no more than 30dp.
Let's say if I add 200 fragments, each of them will have 1dp(assuming that my screen is 200dp) But if I add 3 fragments, I want them to be 30dp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the width of each fragment programatically. You will have to have to width dimension of your windows and divide it by the number of your fragment. If it's > 30 width = 30.

```
int width = sizescreen/nbframent;
if (width > 30)
   width = 30;
frag.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));//do that for each of your child
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried something similar and it didn't work. I tried it again now and it works;)
Thank you, you helped me a lot;)

Comment: lol perfect, can you just put my answer as the correct one please ;)